# Testing Scripts

Tags: cron, testing

If I have a script called teiid.sh set to run daily by a cron job. The scripts purpose is to initialize the startup of teiid.

How would I make a call to test to see the if teiid.sh is working properly with  cron, and not just performing endless actions or no action at all?

Example:

```
@daily * * * * /etc/init.d/teiid.sh jeff@****.edu
```

Would `chkconfig --add /etc/init.d/teiid.sh` help with anything at all?

Comment: If your script is called `script.sh` why do you have `/etc/init.d/teiid.sh` in your crontab?

Comment: sorry I updated it, I was using it for script.sh for explanation purposes. The actual script is teiid.sh

Comment: What are you actually trying to do: have `teiid.sh` run after you boot the computer (seems probable) or make it run every day at midnight (this is what your cronjob would actually do)?

Comment: To clarify: I asked the above question mainly because `/etc/init.d` **is not** the place to put your daily cron jobs, but where system startup scripts reside. System-wide scripts that should be run daily by cron live under `/etc/cron.daily`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do 2 things..

1. check /var/log/cron to check if it's being executed
2. add > /tmp/log 2>&1 to the end of the cron entry. then cat /tmp/log to check if the output is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Making a call to the script to test if it is working properly?
When you wrote it did you test it? Running it with `cron` would be no different.

Other possibilities
 - output of your script to a file
 - trace what your script is doing by adding `-x` to the "shebang"
`#!/bin/bash -x` or put `set x` on the next line after

This will provide the trace output. Either way you need to be able to see this information.
And if you are not there or can not see it you will have to output it to a file.

As far as the chkconfig command. Depending on the distro this will add it to the appropriate runlevels with S start and K kill scripts. Usually if it has the LSB header information. Or you can manually create the symlinks.